# django signal send email after registering user

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have gone through the documentation of signals, but didn't understand much.

When I register a user a signal should be raised and a confirmation mail must be sent to the user.

I didn't understand the process. Can someone give me a good example how I can do this. When a user is registered a notification should be triggered and an email must be sent to the user.

Comment: There are no registration signals. At least not in the auth module. You'll need to make your own.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question, so I will just outline some possibilities and you have to choose how to deal with it.

The easiest and most obvious alternative is to avoid signals altogether. Signals are great, and very important when you need to decouple application. So, for example, if you will have other applications in the futurethat will need to do *something* when the user registers, then signals is a great place to start with.

In this case, you can use the signal [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) on the User model, so when after a user is saved do your logic.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can even define your custom signal and trigger it whenever a user is registered.

There is a great documentation in [Django docs: Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/) with specific examples which are too extensive to present in here.

But if you do not need to decouple your application and simply want to send an email after the user is saved, then you can do so within the very view that handles the user registration. This way you will avoid the extra overhead of coding with signals.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing exactly this:

```
def user_created(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    if created:         
        email_confirmed, email_is_created = EmailConfirmed.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        if email_is_created:
            short_hash = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
            base, domain = str(user.email).split("@")
            activation_key = hashlib.sha1(short_hash+base).hexdigest()
            email_confirmed.activation_key = activation_key
            email_confirmed.save()
            email_confirmed.activate_user_email()

#user_logged_in.connect(get_create_stripe)
post_save.connect(user_created, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Let me give you a gist of what is happening above: 
We have a user_created() function which checks if there exists a user with the same email ID. If not, we shoot an activation email. How? We have post_save in signals (`from django.db.models.signals import post_save`) which at the end of save() sends a signal. More about post_save could be read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save).

You could watch my [repository](https://github.com/ShubhamRathi/Django-ecommerce/blob/master/accounts/signals.py) to get a better birds eye view over the process.